# Print a total column and total row using data from a txt in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginning programmer and my professor has assigned the problem as follows:

A hotel salesperson enters sales for 2012 in a text file, “hotel.txt”.  Each line contains the following separated by a space:
invoiceID serviceCode invoiceDate saleAmount
The invoiceID is an integer,  service code is a value from 0 to 4, the invoiceDate is a string in the format MM/DD/2012, and saleAmount is a double.  The service codes represent  the following:
Service Code    Service
0   Lodging
1   Dining
2   Conferences
3   Receptions
4   Spa

Write a program that reads from file “hotel.txt” and prints to file “hotelAnswer.txt”.   The report should appear similar to the report below.  Replace my name with your name.  Note the sample serves to demonstrate the format to be used for your report. The values shown are not the actual totals for the exam data.  Create your own data file to test your program.  In a separate file (use Notepad, WordPad, or Microsoft Word), explain your rationale in creating your data file. In your submission to Moodle include: (1)your program, (2)your test file,  (3)test file rationale, and (4)your result file.

I have written the code and everything works except for, the last column is not returning the total, it is returning the last element of the last row.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Scanner hotelIn = new Scanner(new File("hotelTest.txt"));
    PrintWriter hotelOut = new PrintWriter(new File("hotelAnswer.txt"));
    double[][] hotelReceipts = new double[MONTHnames.length][SERVICEnames.length];
    double[][] hotelReceiptsTotal = new double[MONTHnames.length][SERVICEnames.length];
    double[][] hotelReceiptsMonthlyTotal = new double[MONTHnames.length]           
                                                            [SERVICEnames.length];


    while(hotelIn.hasNextLine()){
        String inputLine = hotelIn.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
        int serviceCode = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].substring(0,2));
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
        hotelReceipts[month-1][serviceCode] += amount;
        hotelReceipts[month-1][SERVICEnames.length-1] += amount;
        hotelReceipts[MONTHnames.length-1][serviceCode] += amount;
        hotelReceiptsTotal[month][serviceCode]+= amount;
        hotelReceiptsTotal[month][SERVICEnames.length-1] += amount;
        hotelReceiptsTotal[MONTHnames.length-1][serviceCode] += amount;

        //hotelReceiptsMonthlyTotal[month][serviceCode] = total;
    }//read until end of file
    System.out.printf("   Hotel 2012 Receipt Totals by Month and Service Type\n"
            + "            Produced by Ivy R. Sugars\n              "
            + "Date: November 18, 2013\n\n");
    System.out.print("         |");

    for(int i=0;i<SERVICEnames.length;i++){
        System.out.printf("%15s ", SERVICEnames[i]); 
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("_________|__________________________________________"
            + "__________________________________________________________");
    for(int month=0;month<MONTHnames.length-1;month++){
        System.out.printf("%9s| ", MONTHnames[month]);
        for(int i=0;i<SERVICEnames.length;i++){
            System.out.printf("%15.2f ", hotelReceipts[month][i]);
         }//columns
        System.out.println();
    }//rows
    System.out.println("_________|__________________________________________"
            + "___________________________________________________________");
    for (int month = 12; month < MONTHnames.length; month++) {
        System.out.printf("%9s| ", MONTHnames[month]);
        for (int i = 0; i < SERVICEnames.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%15.2f ", hotelReceiptsTotal[month][i]);
        }//columns
    }//rows

    hotelOut.close();
   }//main
}//MyHotel
```

Somebody please help!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson   "everything works except for, the last column is not returning the total, it is returning the last element of the last row."

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).